# Watson doesn't get zeros

Tags: watson-conversation

Let's say I have a conversation services configured in IBM Watson ready to recognize a number given in words and in pieces. For example, if I have the number `1320`, it can be sent as `thirteen twenty` or `thirteen two zero`, etc.
In the first case I'll get something like this from a conversation service:

```
{
    // ...
    "entities": [
        {
            "entity": "sys-number",
            "location": [
                0,
                5
            ],
            "value": "13",
            "confidence": 1,
            "metadata": {
                "numeric_value": 13
            }
        },
        {
            "entity": "sys-number",
            "location": [
                6,
                12
            ],
            "value": "20",
            "confidence": 1,
            "metadata": {
                "numeric_value": 20
            }
        }
    ]
    // ...
}
```

In the second case (`thirteen two zero`):

```
{
    // ...
    "entities": [
        {
            "entity": "sys-number",
            "location": [
                0,
                5
            ],
            "value": "13",
            "confidence": 1,
            "metadata": {
                "numeric_value": 13
            }
        },
        {
            "entity": "sys-number",
            "location": [
                6,
                14
            ],
            "value": "2",
            "confidence": 1,
            "metadata": {
                "numeric_value": 2
            }
        }
    ]
    // ...
}
```

The big question here is: *Where is my zero?*

I know this question has been asked more than once, but none of the answers I found solved my current issues.
I've seen examples where a regular expression could be used, but that's for actual numbers, here I have words and Watson is the one who actually guesses the number.

Is there a way to obtain a third entry in my entities for that zero? or another work arround? or configuration I may be lacking?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this in Watson Assistant and it now gets the zero. With @sys-numbers enabled my utterance is `thirteen two zero` and I get these entities back:

```
entities: [
0: {
  entity: "sys-number", 
  location: [0, 8], 
  value: "13", 
  confidence: 1, 
  metadata: {numeric_value: 13}
}
1: {
  entity: "sys-number", 
  location: [9, 12], 
  value: "2", 
  confidence: 1, 
  metadata: {numeric_value: 2}
}
2: {
  entity: "sys-number", 
  location: [13, 17], 
  value: "0", 
  confidence: 1, 
  metadata: {numeric_value: 0}
}
]
```

It might be the entities matching has been improved.